# Java 11 and E(fx)clipse JavaFX plugin on Eclipse 4.9: An error has occurred - see the log file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin, javafx-11

I can't get my Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) running with Java 11 and E(fx)clipse JavaFX plugin.

I run the typical `Help -> Install new software` procedure for E(fx)clipse, but after restart, Eclipse fully crashes: I can't even open Eclipse anymore for a new workspace!

When I try to run Eclipse, I get a dialog:

> "An error has occurred. See the log file C:\workspace\.metadata\.log"

I've put a copy of that log file on [my Github](https://github.com/acenelio/eclipse4.9-javafx-plugin-log-error/blob/master/.log).

Well, I could run a hello world JavaFX application using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144931/how-to-add-javafx-runtime-to-eclipse-on-java-11) manual library setup, but I'd really like to get E(fx)clipse running in order to get the Eclipse menu options and functionality. So how to solve that? Thanks.

Comment: What is the JavaFX plugin? E(fx)clipse?

Comment: @JoséPereda yes, E(fx)clipse. I've edited my question.

Comment: Looks like some plugins are looking for `javax.xml.bind` which isn't included in Java 11. Until the plugins are fixed you will need to use an older release of Java.

Comment: I've just installed e(fx)clipse 3.3.0 (e(fx)clipse - IDE 3.3.0.201809010700), and Eclipse 2018-09 still works fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Eclipse e(fx)clipse** the support for **Java 11** has just been implemented and is just available [**since version 3.4.1**](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.efxclipse/releases/3.4.1), but according to your log you have version 3.3.0.201809010600.

See [Eclipse bug 539739](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539739)

Comment: Worked thanks! Just to mention, this is the direct URL when installing the plug in: http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.4.1/site/