# How do I link between the new Eclipse and Scene Builder?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have downloaded the latest version of eclipse and the latest version of javafx, created a new user library which contains all of the javafx files (I have used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVn6_2KuYbM) tutorial).

I've noticed that unlike older eclipse versions, there is no "scene builder path" setting in the latest eclipse, and when I attempt to create a new project there is no such thing as "JavaFX Project" (I remember having this option that automatically created an fxml file and control,main classes.)

My question is how do I make it all work together like it used to in the older eclipse versions?

(I know that there's something called e(fx)clipse but I believe it is outdated since it refers to javafx 2, and I have downloaded version 11)

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025063/java-11-and-efxclipse-javafx-plugin-on-eclipse-4-9-an-error-has-occurred-se) help you?

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 partially
now I am able to create a javafx project with main class and css file, but the fxml file does not get created automatically, and when I try to create everything manually i get errors

Comment: what are you doing when you create a fxml file?

Comment: what does it do? what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the eclipse marketplace and install e(fx)clipse. It is not outdated and should provide you with the functionality that you are looking for.