# How to properly set spring context on javaFX with spring?

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX application integrated with Spring and Maven, but I think that Spring context is not working properly with my current configuration.
I want to use repository classes inside my JafaFX application (on a controller class). Spring can import the need configuration for JPA, but when I use `@Autowired` annotation to inject my repository classes, I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to use the injected element.
How could I fix that?

I am starting my application using the approach given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300492/4874945), so I have a main class (`AppLaucnher.java`) that start the FXApplication (`FXLauncher.java`). `FXLauncher.java` starts the spring context that I want to use in the controller class (`DialogLoginController.java`) without success.

On the other hand my repository tests works properly using the Spring context. Below I show my code.

My AppLaucnher.java:

```java
package io.sonoc.reportes.gui.main;

@Slf4j
public class AppLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Starting Spring Boot App");
        //Application.launch(FXLauncher.class);

        // Launch JavaFX with custom Preloader
        LauncherImpl.launchApplication(FXLauncher.class, FXPreloader.class, args);
    }

}
```

The FXLauncher.java class where I initialize the spring context:

```java
package io.sonoc.reportes.gui.main;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@Import({DataSourceConfig.class, JpaConfig.class})
@ComponentScan({"io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control", "io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.domain.d_authorization", "io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.repository.d_authorization"})
@Slf4j
public class FXLauncher extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        // Initializes Spring context
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(FXLauncher.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // JFX runtime calls " Application.stop()" on last window closing
        Platform.setImplicitExit(true);

        log.info("Starting JavaFX with primaryStage on FXLauncher: {}", primaryStage);

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.stop();
    }

}
```

And the Controller class where I want to use my repository classes.

```java
package io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control;

@Controller
@Transactional
@Data
@Slf4j
public class DialogLoginController{

    // Variables
    private static int sessionID = 0;
    private DialogLoginManager dialogLoginManager;
    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository; // my repository class
    private QUser qUser = QUser.user;


         /**
     * Check if login (user) exists on the DB.
     */   
    private String searchLogin() {
        String login = "";
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(1); // here I get the NullPointerException

        log.info("Found user: {}", user);

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            login = user.get().getLogin();
            log.info("User login: {}", login);
        }

        return login;

    }
```

The repository classes looks like:
The `@Entity` User class:

```java
package io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.domain.d_authorization;

/**
 * The persistent class for the user database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
@Table(name="user", schema="d_authorization")
@Data

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="company_id")
    private Integer companyId;

    @Column(name="login")
    private String login;

}
```

The `@Repository` UserRepository class:

```java
package io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.repository.d_authorization;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<User>{

}
```

As an example, my test class works properly:

```java
package io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.repository.d_authorization;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JpaConfig.class })
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private QUser qUser = QUser.user;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(userRepository);
        Optional<User> p = userRepository.findById(1);
        log.info(">>test --> : {}", p);
    }

    @Test // Search for "testUser"
    public void testQueryDsl() {
        Iterable<User> it = userRepository.findAll(qUser.login.contains("testUser"));
        log.info(">>test --> : {}", it);

        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findOne(qUser.login.contains("testUser"));
        log.info(">>test --> Found user: {}", user);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            String login = user.get().getLogin();
            log.info(">>testQueryDsl --> User login: {}", login);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, when I execute the method `searchLogin()` from the `DialogLoginController` class, I get the output below, but I expected a return from the database, as occurs with the test class:

```
2019-07-20 11:16:40,634 INFO  [main] io.sonoc.reportes.gui.main.AppLauncher: Starting Spring Boot App
2019-07-20 11:16:40,892 INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread] io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.PreloaderController: New PreloaderController

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-07-20 11:16:42,926 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.config.DataSourceConfig: Connected to DB: jdbc:postgresql://routing-dev.systemonenoc.com/dedalusdb
2019-07-20 11:16:42,927 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.config.DataSourceConfig: Pool properties: maxActive=50, maxIdle=2, minIdle=1
2019-07-20 11:16:43,015 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.config.JpaConfig: 15 hibernate properties loaded from file /proyecto-hibernate.properties
2019-07-20 11:16:43,196 WARN  [JavaFX-Launcher] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation: HHH020100: The Ehcache second-level cache provider for Hibernate is deprecated.  See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12441 for details.
2019-07-20 11:16:48,972 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.config.JpaConfig: Created to LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@1577331
2019-07-20 11:16:48,981 WARN  [JavaFX-Launcher] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation: HHH020100: The Ehcache second-level cache provider for Hibernate is deprecated.  See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12441 for details.
2019-07-20 11:16:50,151 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] i.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.DialogLoginController: New DialogLoginController
2019-07-20 11:16:50,408 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.DialogLoginManager: New DialogLoginManager
2019-07-20 11:16:50,409 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] i.s.reportes.gui.control.DialogRememberController: New DialogRememberController
2019-07-20 11:16:50,411 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.PreloaderController: New PreloaderController
2019-07-20 11:16:50,415 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.WindowMainController: New WindowMainController
2019-07-20 11:16:50,417 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.WindowMainManager: New WindowMainManager
2019-07-20 11:16:50,431 INFO  [JavaFX-Launcher] io.sonoc.reportes.jpa.config.JpaConfig: Created to PlatformTransactionManager: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@4064e2ac
2019-07-20 11:16:50,741 INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread] io.sonoc.reportes.gui.main.FXLauncher: Starting JavaFX with primaryStage on FXLauncher: javafx.stage.Stage@2447d339
2019-07-20 11:16:50,741 INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread] io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.DialogLoginManager: New DialogLoginManager
2019-07-20 11:16:50,747 INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread] i.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.DialogLoginController: New DialogLoginController
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.DialogLoginController.searchLogin(DialogLoginController.java:143)
    at io.sonoc.reportes.gui.control.DialogLoginController.onButtonAction(DialogLoginController.java:88)
    ... 59 more
```

Could you give some inspiration?

Comment: `@Controller` are used for spring-mvc controller classes, am not sure if they can be used here, can you replace `@Controller` by `@Service` annotation, and see if it works?

Comment: Thank your @sagarr. I tried replacing `@Controller` by `@Service` or `@Component`, but I get the same exception.  I think Spring is creating the `@Component` \ `@Controller` or `@Service` classes properly, but when I use `@Autowired` to inject them, I get `NullPointerExceptions` like that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to have a JFX and Spring integrated app working on Eclipse, was following the comment of user @Cristian [link to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300492/4874945), part 2b).
The problem is not the integration of JFX and Spring context, the issue is the way in which the app should be initialized: "Your main app SHOULD NOT extend Application":

```
public class AppLauncher { // I do not extend from Application.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    log.info("Starting Application: FXLauncher and FXPreloader");

    // Launches JavaFX with custom Preloader (https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/09/javafx-how-to-easily-implement-application-preloader-2/)
    LauncherImpl.launchApplication(FXLauncher.class, FXPreloader.class, args);
 }
}
```

Here, in the class that starts the Spring context and the JFX app, I extend from Application:

```
public class FXLauncher extends Application { // I extend from Application, this class is started in the previous main AppLauncher class
   // Variables
private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

// Initializes variables before start() method
@Override
public void init() throws Exception {

    // Initializes Spring context with custom configuration
    log.info("Triying to load Spring Application Context.");

    try { // To avoid connection problems with external servers
        springContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(GuiConfig.class);
        springContext.getBean(GuiConfig.class);

        log.info("Is a static Spring context availabe?: {}", GuiConfig.getSpringContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Window loadings if necessary, here
      }

 // Starts JavaFX Main App
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
  ...
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ignite helps spring dependency injection to be available in the FX managed lifecycle methods like controller init. https://github.com/gluonhq/ignite

https://gluonhq.com/labs/ignite/

Comment: Thank you @alex-stoneham, It's a great help.