# import javafx can not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am using Windows 10 64-bit and eclipse java 2019-06.I have installed `jdk 12.0.2` and `jre 8u221`. I have set environment system path in environment variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin`.I can easily compile and run `java` file in windows command prompt. I can not import `javafx`.

I have used `e(fx)clipse` (`javafx1` in the following picture). I have also tried adding `jfxswt.jar` into external library(`javafx2` in the following picture).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94KvB.png)

Comment: JavaFX is not part of Java 11+, and must be downloaded separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add JavaFX runtime to Eclipse in Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52144931/5221149)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per this article, [Future of JavaFx](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates)

> Starting with JDK 11, Oracle is making JavaFX
>   easier to adopt by making the technology available as a separate
>   download, decoupled from the JDK.

As you mentioned, you are using `JDK 12.0.2`. `JavaFx` library are no longer part of JDK, they need to be added separately. 
Here you can find official documentation on how to proceed with JavaFX 12 development
[Install JavaFx](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)

Answer (score 3):

JFX is not part of JDK since Java 11. They are now distributed as standalone packages. Some reading can be found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates)

You can either add the OpenJFX libraries by downloading them from [here](https://openjfx.io/), or you can use another JDK distribution such as [Azul](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community), which bundles the OpenJFX with their OpenJDK distributions.