# how to run openjfx 11 in the commandline

Tags: java, openjfx

after I have installed openjdk-11.jdk and openjfx I was able to get openjfx ip and running within Eclipse following this thread:
[How to add JavaFX runtime to Eclipse in Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144931/how-to-add-javafx-runtime-to-eclipse-in-java-11)

But all my attempts to let it run in the command line failed (I have added the path to the openfx as well: /usr/share/openjfx/lib).
Within the bin folder `/test-fx/bin` I call
`java application.Main` and I receive `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`
Conclusion: Java does find Main.main(), but cannot find the JavaFX Application class.
test-fx is just my Eclipse folder.
the structure is like this:

```
test-fx
    src
        application
            Main.java
    bin
        application
            Main.class
```

And this is Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Does anybody know a good solution on that? What is recommended?
How should I define PATH, where should it point to?

Comment: You should give your command line.

Comment: I have updated my thread above.

Comment: What is test-fx? Is that the output from using jlink? Also, when you call `java` is that the system java you're calling?

Comment: I have updated my thread above.

Comment: You haven't added the javafx libraries when you try to run the code. You're just using the system java. You should be able to use. `java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls -cp . application.Main` example from here. https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/CommandLine/Non-modular/CLI note that $PATH_TO_FX is the path to your fx libraries.

Comment: Thank you, that works! 
To everybody else reading this thread: Do not change the general PATH. Neither JAVA_HOME nor JAVAFX_HOME is required.