# cant seem to add javaFX JDK to my project

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have downloaded e(fx)clipse from eclipse market place and created a new JavaFX project but I still get the error JavaFX can not be resolved and the library does not show up

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Faisal, welcome to StackOverflow. Have you looked at [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144931/how-to-add-javafx-runtime-to-eclipse-in-java-11)

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/