# JavaFX 11 Eclipse e(fx)clipse sample project error

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I am using JavaFX 11 with Eclipse, i used e(fx)clipse to generate sample project but it gives this error, nothing was changed or added in this project. What can cause such behavior on just sample auto-generated project? I can see that there may be problem with loading class but i don't know how to fix it.
Main.java

```java
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

SampleController.java

```java
package application;

public class SampleController {
    
}
```

Sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
    <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</AnchorPane>
```

Error message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 10 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Comment: Make sure you included the javafx Libary and add-modules setting for the VM [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144931/how-to-add-javafx-runtime-to-eclipse-in-java-11)

Comment: For an FXML project, you need to explicitly add the `javafx.fxml` module as well as `javafx.controls`. I.e. (assuming you are not making a modular project) your runtime VM arguments need to include `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`.

Comment: As an alternative to adding the OpenJFX libraries, you can use a JDK that bundles them. At least two: ZuluFX by Azul Systems, and LibericaFX by BellSoft. And consider using current version of JavaFX, as it has been under active development.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i did not add module javafx.fxml to run arguments.