# In Eclipse, how do you create an .exe file of your project

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, launch4j

Been stuck on this for 3 days.
My app uses JavaFX and it runs perfectly fine when I press the "Play" button.
I want to create a runnable .exe file. Here is the pom.xml of my project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.schematix</groupId>
    <artifactId>schematix</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Building electricity calculator</description>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <runtime.version>7.0.0.Final</runtime.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have the Compiler Compliance Level set to 17.

I created a JAR file like this: Right-click on my project in Project Explorer, select **Export**, select **Runnable JAR file**, click Next, select **Extract required libraries into generated JAR** and choose the correct Launch configuration (Main - schematix) and an export destination.

I then opened the *Launch4j* program, and in the **Basic** tab added the output .exe file's destination, selected the Jar file, selected a .ico file for the icon. I also went to the **JRE** tab and set the min JRE version to 17. That's all I did. I then pressed the Build wrapper button and it generated the .exe. When I try to run that .exe using the Test wrapper button in Launch4j I get the following error:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run
> this application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing error " JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" while running jar file in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273767/showing-error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-t)

Comment: @experimentunit1998X which comment?

Comment: The comment by TechGeek on the post. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144931/how-to-add-javafx-runtime-to-eclipse-in-java-11 Does this link answer your question?"

Comment: Isn't that for adding JavaFX to eclipse?

Comment: well comparing the two threads, the answers seems similar, but the link by TechGeek seemed even more in depth. i figured it should be applicable. but you should be correct that it might be a different issue entirely

Comment: Related: [How to create a standalone .exe in Java (that runs without an installer and a JRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811401/how-to-create-a-standalone-exe-in-java-that-runs-without-an-installer-and-a-jr/69824145#69824145)

Comment: `1.8`source and target settings for maven compile plugin are very old, probably use `17` if you are targeting jre 17+

Comment: I set `<source>17</source>` and `<target>17</target>`. Still the same issue.

Comment: Yes the version specifier in Maven is not your only issue.  Another issue is that JavaFX cannot find the native libraries it needs to run because you have not packaged your application correctly. If you follow the guide I referenced correctly, which is a completely different packaging approach, it should work IMO. Alternately follow the runtime images section of the [getting started documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), or use a tool such as jpackage to create an installer, for which you can find documentation on the web, but is more difficult to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface:**

Eclipse can't do that out of the box and launch4j is not really good. Use one of Oracles applications called "jpackage" instead to do this. Or "jlink".

You need to create a fat JAR. A fat JAR is a JAR, which contains all needed dependencies additionally to the standard JDK dependencies. JavaFX dependencies are not part of the standard anymore, so you have to create a fat JAR.

I posted the same answer here and it worked: [EXE using launch4j does not work (javafx project), JAR files need to be ran from the console specifying the VM argument of the javafx location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989018/exe-using-launch4j-does-not-work-javafx-project-jar-files-need-to-be-ran-from/71990054#71990054)

**Example working JavaFX application with gradle and fat JAR task:**

https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

**Example working JavaFX application with maven and fat JAR goal:**

https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

**Example pom.xml for creating a fat JAR with the shade plugin:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaFxAppMavenNonModular</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <name>JavaFxAppMavenNonModular</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
        <mainclassnameparam>your.groupid.javafxappnonmodular.MainApplicationLauncher</mainclassnameparam>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${mainclassnameparam}</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${mainclassnameparam}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Create EXE out of fat JAR:**

You can use jpackage for this. It is very easy to use.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

**Create EXE/MSI with an external application:**

You need JDK 17 installed.

This application allows you to configure an icon, installer, etc. in a simple GUI. It creates the needed jpackage command for you, which you can just copy and execute it local, OR you can execute the command in the wrapped JDK 17.

https://github.com/davidweber411/Java2NativeWinConverter

How to Install?

1. Clone this repository
2. Navigate to the project
3. Execute the gradle task "createCustomFatJar".

   Windows:
   .\gradlew createCustomFatJar
4. Double click on the created fat JAR.

Comment: Forgive me for asking but is this something I use inside Eclipse? I'm using Maven if that makes any difference

Comment: Yes to everything BUT the external application and  "jpackage". Jpackage is part of the JDK itself since jdk17.

Comment: Your best bet is to download this template Project https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppMavenNonModular. Then import it into eclipse. Everything is preconfigured fine.

Comment: I added a guide with pictures in the Github repository for "how to import in Eclipse IDE".