# JavaFX & Eclipse -> Stage not opening

Tags: java, javafx

When i try to run a FX program there is no window opening, instead there is just a empty java folder popping up in my dock (i'm on mac os). I am currently running the newest version of Eclipse,jdk-17.0.1.jdk from Oracle and javafx-sdk-17.0.1 from Gluon.
There is no error in my console, vm arguments are correct 100% and i unchecked the second box. The build path is also correct.

The program is also working 100%, as i had it running perfectly in the past and i didn't change anything bout it. I even asked my prof. for help but he couldn't find the reason for FX not working.

Yall got any ideas whats the problem?

Comment: (a) Can you add minimal code here to reproduce the problem? (b) Does it work when started from a console instead of from Eclipse? I also had some problems with JavaFX in Eclipse some time ago, but did not try it lately. Back then, this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300492/1639625

Comment: First try with JavaFX 18-ea+6. There have been some bugs recently. Maybe you were hit by these.

Comment: Do you have the JavaFX-swt libraries included? If so, Eclipse will automatically check a box marked “Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument” in the Run configurations pane, under the “Arguments” tab. Uncheck that box.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.