# add JavaFX runtime to Eclipse in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

i got this error when i want to run my project as a java application on eclipse : "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application."
i followed the answer to a similar question here on StackOverflow " [How to add JavaFX runtime to Eclipse in Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144931/how-to-add-javafx-runtime-to-eclipse-in-java-11)  but they are using the JDK 11 and JavaFX 11, and I'm using now the latest version of eclipse 4.23.0 the jdk15 and JavaFX 17. so when i follow the instructions Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> New. i don't find "User Libraries" under build path.
I don't know how to fix this issue and the error mentioned.?

Comment: Unfold Build Path entry in the tree and there is User Libraries

Comment: I can't check on Windows but on macOS it is still there.

Comment: By the way, Java 15 is end-of-life and not receiving updates. You really should move to Java 17 (LTS) or the current Java 18.

Comment: The answer you linked links to a [comprehensive tutorial on getting started with JavaFX in Eclipse](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse) using the recommended JavaFX 17.0.1+ version.  Also, ensure your IDE is up to date.  From the linked getting started documentation, I'd recommend the "Modular with Maven" setup unless you require third-party libraries that don't interact well with the Java module system or you know and prefer Gradle over Maven.